Is limit of non constant polynomial $p(z)$ approaches infinity as $z$ approaches infinity?
Question : Let $p(z)=a_0 +a_1z+... +a_n z^n$ be a non constant polynomial. Then does $p(z)\rightarrow\infty$ as $z\rightarrow\infty$ ?
In the below picture, the author directly writes $\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty} p(z) = \infty$ where $p(z)=a_0 +a_1z+... +a_n z^n$ and $a_n\neq 0$
But, I think he is wrong!. Because, if we consider, $p(z)=-z$ then $\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty} p(z) =\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty} -z=-\infty$
Am I correct? So what should the result be and how can I prove that result?
Please help.


What is $Q(z)$ in the book? Could it be that $P(z)$ was defined as $a_0+a_1z+…+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+z^n$ in the book?

In complex analysis the standard is to have a single point at infinity, i.e., the one point compactification of $\mathbb{C}$ called the Riemann sphere. So $-\infty$ is the same as $\infty$: otherwise, we would have to have $i\infty$, and $e^{2\pi i / 7}\infty$, and so on.

@SohamSaha $Q(z) =\frac{1}{p(z)}$

@SohamSaha how could be that? Pic clearly, shows that $lim_{z\rightarrow\infty}Q(z) =0$

@emilg, so why some author prefers to write $\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty}|p(z)|=\infty$

As in the very astute comment above, the extended complex plane is basically the one-point compactification of $\Bbb R^2,$ known as the Riemann sphere.
And there's only one point at infinity.   You may want to familiarize yourself with stereographic projection.  The point at infinity is often identified with the north pole, and one gets closer and closer to it as one goes towards the horizon in any direction.
Take a polynomial,  $p(z)=a_nz^n+\dots +a_1z+a_0.$  Write $p(z)=a_nz^n(1+\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_nz}+\dots+\frac {a_1}{a_nz^{n-1}}+\frac{a_0}{a_nz^n})\to \infty $ as $z\to \infty. $  That's asymptotically, $p(z)\sim a_nz^n,$ since the expression in parentheses goes to $1.$
As alluded to in @emilg's comment, we run into some problems otherwise.
For instance,  look at your example $p(z)=-z.$  If there's more than one infinity then we get different answers if $z$ increases without bound in different directions.    If we had $z\to-\infty ,$ we'd have $p(z) $ goes to $-\infty$ as $z\to \infty $ and that it goes to $\infty$ as $z\to -\infty.$
So, basically $f(z)\to \infty $ means $\mid f(z)\mid \to\infty. $
But remember you have examples like $e^z,$ which blows up as you approach infinity on the $x$-axis, and to zero as you go in the negative direction; whereas it moves around the unit circle as you go along the imaginary axis.  So there's no limit at all.
The image is dense though,  as with any non-constant entire function.

Sir, so what happens with those function, whose limit approches different values as $z\rightarrow\infty$ along different direction (say, $0$ if $z$ approches to $\infty$ from one direction and $\infty$ if $z$ approches to $\infty$ from other direction). Is their, limit does not exists or they also tends to $\infty$ ?

If the limits are unbounded,  they approach infinity.   If one or more is unbounded,  others bounded,  no limit.
